# __setattr__ only for names not found in the object's attributes`?

Tags: python, getattr, setattr

I want to use `__setattr__` only when the attribute was not found in the object's attributes, like `__getattr__`.

Do I really have to use *try-except*?

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    try:
        setattr(super(Clazz, self), name, value)
    except AttributeError:
        # implement *my* __setattr__
        pass
```

Comment: Well, you could use `if hasattr()`...

Comment: Well, the documentation is pretty explicit about it... what's more to ask?

Comment: You could make a decorator to do it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`hasattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if hasattr(super(Clazz, self), name):
        setattr(super(Clazz, self), name, value)
    else:
        # implement *my* __setattr__
        pass
```

Comment: A setattr in the object returned by "super" does not work. At all. "super" returns a special lazy evaluation object that retrieves attributes from the superclass, not the actual superclass.

Comment: (as you can see in my answer, using `super(...).__setattr__(...)` works, though, as opposed to `setattr(super(...), ...)`

Answer (score 3):

There are many times when calling `hasattr` won't work the way you expect (e.g., you've overridden `__getattr__` to always return a value), so another way to set the right attribute in the right place would be something like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, k, v):
    if k in self.__dict__ or k in self.__class__.__dict__:
        super(Clazz, self).__setattr__(k, v)
    else:
        # implement *my* __setattr__
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`__setattr__`, if it exists, is called for every attribute set on the object.

Your example code, though, is rather confusing for me. What are you trying to do with the statement:
`setattr(super(Clazz, self), name, value)`  ??

Set an attribute on self, with self viewed as an instance of its superclass? That makes no sense, because the object is still "self".

On the other hand trying to use "setattr" on the object returned by a call to "super" will always yield an attribute error, regardless if the attribute exists on the superclass or not. That is because super returns not the superclass itself, but a wrapper object that wil fetch attributes there when they are needed - so you can use "hasattr" in the object returned by super, but not setattr. I thought it would behave so, and just tried it on the console :

```
>>> class A(object):pass
... 
>>> class B(A): pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> super(B,b)
<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>
>>> setattr(super(B,b), "a", 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> A.a = 1
>>> setattr(super(B,b), "a", 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

But then, you can just use "hasattr" in the object itself, and proceed like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if hasattr(self, value):
        #this works because retrieving "__setattr__" from the 
        # result of the supercall gives the correct "__setattr__" of the superclass.
        super(Clazz, self).__setattr__(self, attr, value)
    else:
        # transform value /or attribute as desired in your code
        super(Clazz, self).__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

Comment: Not much time, will look at it later, thanks for your answer. But `setattr(obj, name, value)` is equal to `obj.__setattr__(name, value)`.

Comment: Not when your "obj" is a call to "super", as demonstrated above.